# Environment variable LC_ALL is always unset by default. why LC_ALL is unset?

Tags: linux, unix, locale

Why `LC_ALL` is always unset by default on Linux and Unix machines?

For example, on Linux:

```
root@icubes:[~]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

And here on AIX:

```
root@matic:[/]# locale
LANG=en_US
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Good question !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's normal; it's not supposed to be set during normal use. The purpose of LC_ALL is to override *all other locale settings* (i.e. `LANG` and `LC_*`), so the only time you would set it is when you wanted to temporarily run some specific program under a different locale.

So if you had LC_ALL set by default, all that would happen is it would make all of the other locale parameters useless.

(The priority order is `LANG` < `LC_*` < `LC_ALL`. All of the individual parameters get their initial values from LANG and can be independently customized using LC_*, but LC_ALL will override all of them.)